# Can I use vscode file-icons in a webview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

**Is it possible to have access or use file icons inside a webview**? *The icons on the side of each file/folder in the explorer.*

My project has a custom activity bar, where I would like to show icons for a file type, preferably using the current Icon Theme, is this possible?

I've seen that code icons can be used, injecting the css in the webview:

```ts
const codiconsUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
    vscode.Uri.joinPath(extensionUri, 'node_modules', 'vscode-codicons', 'dist', 'codicon.css'),
);
```

Then used like this inside the webview's HTML:

```html
<i class="codeicons codeicons-beaker"></i>
```

But I have not been able to find any reference about how to do this with file icons.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
I notice that the error code is `401`(Unauthorized) when loading the `codicon.css`.
[image]

But it works if I copy the `codicon.css` and `codicon.ttf` files to the other folder which is the same level as the `node_modules`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this issue: Make sure that you provided correct `localResourceRoots` to your webview settings. This setting controls which resources you can fetch from within webview.

Example:

```
localResourceRoots: [
                Uri.joinPath(this.__extensionPath, 'node_modules/vscode-codicons'),
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are not file icons. The question is how to use the file icons which comes together with the icon theme. So as i've seen it is not provided and not gonna be provided to the webviews.